# I can not get more than 20 images from google images with selenium

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, google-colaboratory

I am trying to scrape images in google colab from google images with selenium. I can't understand why there is 20 images and why these images are randomly selected and suddenly code crashing. Here is my codes:

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")

options.headless = True

driver = webdriver.Chrome("/usr/bin/chromedriver", options=options)
url = ("https://www.google.com/search?q={s}&tbm=isch&tbs=sur%3Afc&hl=en&ved=0CAIQpwVqFwoTCKCa1c6s4-oCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAC&biw=1251&bih=568")

driver.get(url.format(s='cubism'))

for x in range(10): 
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(5)

imgResults = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//img[contains(@class,'Q4LuWd')]")

src = []
for img in imgResults:
    src.append(img.get_attribute('src'))

for i in range(2000):    
  urllib.request.urlretrieve(str(src[i]),"/content/drive/MyDrive/painting_dataset/cubism/cubism{}.jpg".format(i))
```

And here is my error:

```
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-ae82ebc8b1a5> in <module>
      1 for i in range(2000):
----> 2   urllib.request.urlretrieve(str(src[i]),"/content/drive/MyDrive/painting_dataset/cubism/cubism{}.jpg".format(i))

5 frames
/usr/lib/python3.9/urllib/request.py in _parse(self)
    373         self.type, rest = _splittype(self._full_url)
    374         if self.type is None:
--> 375             raise ValueError("unknown url type: %r" % self.full_url)
    376         self.host, self.selector = _splithost(rest)
    377         if self.host:

ValueError: unknown url type: 'None'
```

Comment: It looks like some of the strings in the `src` list are `None`. Why aren't you using `for i in src:` instead of `for i in range(2000):`? You're probably running off the end of the `src` list.

Comment: It is not about range of for loop. Also I need 2000 images.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the complete solution to save all the images, be it a base64 or an image URL, ignoring the 'None'.

```
import time
from PIL import Image
import requests
import base64
import io
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver import ChromeOptions
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

options = ChromeOptions()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
# options.add_argument("--headless")
options.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
options.add_experimental_option("useAutomationExtension", False)
options.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])

driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)

url = ("https://www.google.com/search?q={s}&tbm=isch&tbs=sur%3Afc&hl=en&ved=0CAIQpwVqFwoTCKCa1c6s4-oCFQAAAAAdAAAAABAC&biw=1251&bih=568")

driver.get(url.format(s='cubism'))

for x in range(10):
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
    time.sleep(2)

imgResults = driver.find_elements(By.XPATH,"//img[contains(@class,'Q4LuWd')]")

src = [img.get_attribute('src') for img in imgResults]
print(len(src))

for i in range(len(src)):
    # check if the image is None
    if src[i] is None:
        pass
    else:
        # if it's base64 images
        if src[i].startswith('data'):
            imgdata = base64.b64decode(str(src[i]).split(',')[1])
            img = Image.open(io.BytesIO(imgdata))
            img.save(f"D:\\test\\cubism{i}.png")
        # if it's image url
        else:
            img = Image.open(requests.get(src[i], stream=True).raw).convert('RGB')
            img.save(f"D:\\test\\cubism{i}.jpg")
```